# Export TIFF from ArcGlobe viewer

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcglobe

I'm attempting to export the current view to a TIFF (I attempted JPEG as well) image in ArcGlobe, but it seems most paths to this are broken in ArcGlobe even though the first two of these work in ArcMap. TIFFs can be exported in ArcGlobe within the application menu so some way must work. **Is there another way?**

1. This one gives me a NotImplementedException

```
    void CreateTIFFFromActiveView(IActiveView activeView, string pathFileName)
    {
        //get pixel boundary of the active view
        Rect rect = default(Rect);
        GetWindowRect(activeView.ScreenDisplay.hWnd, ref rect);
        var envelope = new Envelope() as IEnvelope;
        envelope.PutCoords(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
        var exportRect = new tagRECT()
        {
            top = rect.Top,
            bottom = rect.Bottom,
            right = rect.Right,
            left = rect.Left
        };

        IExport export = new ExportTIFF() as IExport;
        export.ExportFileName = pathFileName;
        export.Resolution = 600;
        export.PixelBounds = envelope;
        int hDC = export.StartExporting();

        //NotImplementedException HERE
        activeView.Output(hDC, 600, ref exportRect, activeView.Extent, null); 

        // Finish writing the export file and cleanup any intermediate files
        export.FinishExporting();
        export.Cleanup();
    }
```

2. This one causes an AccessViolationException

```
    void exportTif(string outputPath)
    {
        var activeView = ArcGlobe.Document.Scene as IActiveView;

        Rect rect = default(Rect);
        GetWindowRect(activeView.ScreenDisplay.hWnd, ref rect);
        var envelope = new Envelope() as IEnvelope;
        envelope.PutCoords(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);

        var docPrintExport = new PrintAndExport();

        var tifExport = new ExportTIFF() as IExport;
        tifExport.ExportFileName = outputPath;
        tifExport.PixelBounds = envelope;
        tifExport.Resolution = 600; 

        //AccessViolationException
        docPrintExport.Export(activeView, tifExport, 600, false, null);
      }
```

3. This one just leaves me with a blank image

```
    void drawBmp()
    {
        _bmp = new Bitmap(2000, 1000);
        _gfx = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp);
        _hdc = (int)_gfx.GetHdc();
    
        var globeDoc = ArcGlobe.Application.Document as IGMxDocument;
        var globe = globeDoc.Scene as IGlobe2;
        var activeView = globe as IActiveView;
        activeView.Draw(_hdc, null);
    
        //just wait 30 seconds for drawing and whatever else
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
        timer.Elapsed += (o, args) =>
        {
            _context.Post(x =>
            {
                _bmp.Save(outputPath);
                _gfx.ReleaseHdc((IntPtr)_hdc);
                _gfx.Dispose();
                _bmp.Dispose();
            }, null);
        };
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();
    }
```

4. This one works, but is limited to the current resolution of the active view which is smaller than I need

```
    void snapShot(string outputPath)
    {
        var globeDoc = ArcGlobe.Application.Document as IGMxDocument;
        var globe = globeDoc.Scene as IGlobe2;
        var activeView = globe as IActiveView;
    
        Rect rect = default(Rect);
        GetWindowRect(activeView.ScreenDisplay.hWnd, ref rect);
        
        globe.GlobeDisplay.ActiveViewer.GetSnapshot(rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top, esri3DOutputImageType.BMP, outputPath);
    }
```